# Python- Access excel files from SharePoint- Download the excel file in the local folder or store it in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, sharepoint

I need to download or read the  excel file from the sharepoint link. I tried multiple approaches from the google already but  getting 403 access error - Forbidden.Is the url issue a problem or am i missing any step to include  to read the file and store in dataframe or to download dataframe.
Appreciate help

Below is the code tried out of multiple approaches:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
file ="https://sites.ey.com/:x:/r/sites/TProjects-Analytics/Dgs/Analytics%10Analytics/Test.xlsx?d=w9d887d3b4ee579e35tdkka&osf=6&wrew=1&e=hjsgdj"
        
username = 'abc@gmail.com'
password = 'Password12@'
        
resp=requests.get(file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)) ## here the output i get as403 
output = open('Test.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

Expected Output :
The test.xlsx to be downloaded in the local folder or to be stored in dataframe.

Comment: Are you sure is a good URL? can you access it?

Comment: yes this is the path which i coped from my sharepoint.

Comment: Modified the path "https://sites.ey.com/sites/TProjects-Analytics/Dgs/AceEngage_Text%10Analytics/Test.xlsx?web=2"   to see but  i get this error while opening the excel file in my local drive "   as cannot open the file due due to incorrect extension or corrupted file.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?